# What causes a NullReferenceException in .NET Threading / accepting TCP connections?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

In my own webserver software, I am getting entries in the Event Viewer on the server that contain the following stack trace:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
Stack:
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

Needless to say, this crashes the process, which means the server goes down.

Since none of the stacktrace mentions my own code, I am quite puzzled. Is this a bug in .NET? If so, are there any known workarounds? Or is there a known cause to this particular exception?

The name `CompletionPortCallback` mentioned in the stacktrace leads me to believe that it occurs when the server tries to accept an incoming TCP connection, so I’m going to include the relevant code for that below. Of course I’m happy to include other code if you think the problem lies elsewhere.

The call to `BeginAccept` looks like this:

```
_listeningSocket.BeginAccept(acceptSocket, null);
```

Here, `_listeningSocket` is of type `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`.

The `acceptSocket` method is shown below. I am going to assume that the comments explain the code well enough; if not, I’m happy to clarify in a comment. Since this code runs in RELEASE mode on the live server, the `#if DEBUG` will of course be false.

```
private void acceptSocket(IAsyncResult result)
{
#if DEBUG
    // Workaround for bug in .NET 4.0 and 4.5:
    // https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535917
    new Thread(() =>
#endif
    {
        // Ensure that this callback is really due to a new connection (might be due to listening socket closure)
        if (!IsListening)
            return;

        // Get the socket
        Socket socket = null;
        try { socket = _listeningSocket.EndAccept(result); }
        catch (SocketException) { } // can happen if the remote party has closed the socket while it was waiting for us to accept
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
        catch (NullReferenceException) { if (_listeningSocket != null) throw; } // can happen if StopListening is called at precisely the "wrong" time

        // Schedule the next socket accept
        if (_listeningSocket != null)
            try { _listeningSocket.BeginAccept(acceptSocket, null); }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { if (_listeningSocket != null) throw; } // can happen if StopListening is called at precisely the "wrong" time

        // Handle this connection
        if (socket != null)
            HandleConnection(socket);
    }
#if DEBUG
    ).Start();
#endif
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you should pass the `_listeningSocket` in the `BeginAccept()` call instead of null: `_listeningSocket.BeginAccept(acceptSocket, _listeningSocket);` see the docs and examples. That's why you received the ArgumentNull exception.

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the .NET framework. If you had msiused the API the error would have occurred right then, not deep in the bowels of the BCL on an IO callback. The question now is how to work around it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is as simple as it is disappointing.

It turns out that the `ArgumentNullException` was indeed thrown by my own code, which executed in the callback to the async call and *should have been* in the stack trace. I trusted the stack trace too much; the fact that this didn’t show in the stack trace led me on a wrong track for a long time.

As C# developers know, the `throw;` statement (not `throw e;`) is supposed to keep the exception stack trace unaltered. `System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback` catches and rethrows the exception via such a `throw;` statement, yet the stack trace shown in the Event Viewer became truncated. I can only surmise that this is a bug in the CLR or the Event Viewer or some interaction between the two, causing only the part of the stack trace from the `throw;` instruction onwards to show.

When I ran the software on the console instead of as a service, which I should have thought of much sooner, the full stack trace of the exception showed on the console, indicating that the true cause of the exception was my own code.

Comment: thank you for answering your own question, your suggestion that the stacktrace was truncated and to run it as a console helped me out a lot. In my case I was expecting my WebException.response to be filled where it was not -> nullreference -> blew my nservicebus service out of the water without any error

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535917 and my own experience, this is likely a knock-on exception from another earlier issue.

Try adding a global exception handler and log & flush all exceptions to disk, then check the log file after a crash to find the real cause.

Answer (score -1):

I think this Exception is thrown because you pass a null reference as the second parameter.

From MSDN Socket.BeginAccept Documentation(http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/5bb431f9.aspx):

> You must create a callback method that implements the AsyncCallback delegate and pass its name to the BeginAccept method. To do this, at the very minimum, you must pass the listening Socket object to BeginAccept through the state parameter. If your callback needs more information, you can create a small class to hold the Socket and the other required information. Pass an instance of this class to the BeginAccept method through the state parameter.

Comment: This is not it. It doesn’t care about the *state* parameter at all. It just stores it unaltered in the `IAsyncResult` object where you can retrieve it in the callback. It can be `null` just fine and this has always worked for me.